# oscap-vm fails to produce HTML results

Tags: openscap

I am getting started with oscap-vm, basically using openscap in an offline mode to scan VM images looking for CVEs.

When I use oscap-vm installed on RHEL7.6 and scan Ubuntu [images](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/bionic/current/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64.img), oscap-vm fails with bunch of errors and fails to produce a HTML or an XML report.

A sample cmd invocation

```
oscap-vm image bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64.img oval eval --report report.html --results results.xml scap-security-guide-0.1.44/ssg-ubuntu1804-ds.xml
```

Some of the errors are of the form:

> OpenSCAP Error: Unable to close probe sd [oval_probe_ext.c:424] Unable
>   to receive a message from probe [oval_probe_ext.c:579] Invalid oval
>   result type: -1. [oval_resultTest.c:179] Unable to close probe sd
>   [oval_probe_ext.c:424] Unable to receive a message from probe
>   [oval_probe_ext.c:579] Invalid oval result type: -1.
>   [oval_resultTest.c:179]

Not sure what am I doing wrong.